# Oracle: Query to find Instance associated with database

Tags: oracle

Need the following queries to understand the Oracle architecture.

1. Query to Find the instance associated with database?
2. Query to find the schema associated with database?
3. Query to find the users (with any privilege) associated with Schema?

Answer (score 1):

1. `select * from gv$instance;`
2. `select * from dba_users;`
3. Schema and user are the same things in Oracle databases.

Comment: SELECT * FROM V$INSTANCE Provide the instance detail. But want to know the database (data file, control file, SP-FILE) associated with that instance

Comment: select * from V$DATABASE provided database detail...How we can correlate V$DATABASE and V$INSTANCE